# How to remove the stroke around the single points in a highcharts area. Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a plotted single point data on my highcharts with chart type ="area".
here is the code:

```
                    xtype: 'container',
                    ref: 'chartContainer',
                    height: 170,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'qxhighchart',
                        ref: '../confirmedChart',
                        cls: 'qx-highchart-ct severity-chart',
                        flex: 1,
                        showLegend: true,
                        chartConfig: Qx.chart.Highchart.Configs.get('area', 
                         {

                            xAxis: {
                                 labels: {
                                     formatter: function () {
                                         return this.value; 
                                     }
                                 }
                             },
                             yAxis: {
                                 labels: {
                                     formatter: function () {
                                         return this.value;
                                     }
                                 }
                             },
                            plotOptions: {
                              area: {
                                  marker: {
                                      enabled: true,
                                      states: {
                                          hover: {
                                              enabled: true
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              },
                                series: {
                                    allowPointSelect: true,
                                    shadow: false,
                                    dataLabels: {
                                      enabled: false
                                    },
                                    marker: {
                                      states: {
                                        select: {
                                          fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
                                          radius: 5,
                                          lineColor: null
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                            },
                                series: [{
                                        name: "A",
                                        id: "a",
                                        type: 'area',
                                        color: '#d5bcfc',
                                        lineColor: '#d5bcfc'
                                    },{
                                          name: "B",
                                          id: "b",
                                          type: 'area',
                                          color: '#5da7e3',
                                          lineColor: '#5da7e3'
                                      }]

                        })
     }]
```

The output of the is attached:

[image]

As you can see I'm getting a stoke fill with a blue color around the single points. I want to get rid of them. From the above code, I tried removing few properties but that didnt help.
here is what I'm expecting the look of single points something like below with all circle shapes

[image]

Any ideas around how to remove the border from the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a border (stroke) by setting `plotOptions.series.marker.lineWidth = 0`. To change all points to circle shape set `plotOptions.series.marker.symbol = 'circle'`.

**Code:**

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    marker: {
      lineColor: null,
      lineWidth: 0,
      symbol: 'circle'
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zLn8o2tf/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker.lineWidth
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.marker.symbol